# Can't figure out a proper MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following structure:

```
id | workerID | materialID | date | materialGathered
```

Different workers contribute different amounts of different material per day. A single worker can only contribute once a day, but not necessarily every day.

What I need to do is to figure out which of them was the most productive and which of them was the least productive, while it is supposed to be measured as AVG() material gathered per day.

I honestly have no idea how to do that, so I'll appreciate any help.

EDIT1:

Some sample data

```
1 | 1 | 2013-01-20 | 25
2 | 1 | 2013-01-21 | 15
3 | 1 | 2013-01-22 | 17
4 | 1 | 2013-01-25 | 28
5 | 2 | 2013-01-20 | 23
6 | 2 | 2013-01-21 | 21
7 | 3 | 2013-01-22 | 17
8 | 3 | 2013-01-24 | 15
9 | 3 | 2013-01-25 | 19
```

Doesn't really matter how the output looks, to be honest. Maybe a simple table like that:

```
workerID | avgMaterialGatheredPerDay
```

And I didn't really attempt anything because I literally have no idea, haha.

EDIT2:

Any time period that is in the table (from earliest to latest date in the table) is considered.

Material doesn't matter at the moment. Only the arbitrary units in the materialGathered column matter.

Comment: Include a sample of what the output should look like, and some sample rows would be helpful.    Also, show any query you've attempted to so far...

Comment: Before you write a query, you must be sure that you understand the requirement completely. What time span do you want to consider in your query? Then: does it make a difference what material was gathered? Or is one kg sand plus one kg gold = two kg? What if the time span is ten days and a worker worked two days in that time and gathered two kg? Is that an avarage of 1 kg per (worked) day or an avarage of 0.2 kg per day (in the time span)?

Comment: I added some edits, my bad.

Comment: Okay. As to SQL: do you know how to select *all* workers and for each their avarage material gathered?

Comment: Wait, disreggard what i said. I do know how to select them all and count their avg material gathered, but I do not know how to count that per day.

Comment: So we are back to the question: 2 days worked in 10 days, gathered 2 kg, makes an avg of 2 / 2 = 1 or 2 / 10 = 0.2 kg?

Comment: Definitely the former :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in your comments you say that we look at each worker and consider their avarage daily working skill, rather than checking which worked most in a given time, the answer is rather easy: Group by workerid to get a result record per worker, use AVG to get their avarage amount:

```
select workerid, avg(materialgathered) as avg_gathered
from work
group by workerid;
```

Now to the best and worst workers. These can be more than two. So you cannot just take the first or last record, but need to know the maximum and the minimum avg_gathered.

```
select max(avg_gathered) as max_avg_gathered, min(avg_gathered) as min_avg_gathered
from
(
  select avg(materialgathered) as avg_gathered
  from work
  group by workerid
);
```

Now join the two queries to get all workers that worked the avarage minimum or maximum:

```
select work.*
from
(
  select workerid, avg(materialgathered) as avg_gathered
  from work
  group by workerid
) as worker
inner join
(
  select max(avg_gathered) as max_avg_gathered, min(avg_gathered) as min_avg_gathered
  from
  (
    select avg(materialgathered) as avg_gathered
    from work
    group by workerid
  )
) as worked on worker.avg_gathered in (worked.max_avg_gathered, worked.min_avg_gathered)
order by worker.avg_gathered;
```

There are other ways to do this. For example with `HAVING avg(materialgathered) IN (select min(avg_gathered)...) OR avg(materialgathered) IN (select max(avg_gathered)...)` instead of a join. The join is very effective though, because you need just one select for both min and max.